# What am I missing about the definition presented here for an image f[a] in "Set Theory for the Working Mathematician" by Krzysztof Ciesielski?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *Set Theory for the Working Mathematician* by Krzysztof Ciesielski, he gives the definition of an image as follows.

For f : X → Y , A ⊂ X, we define

f[A] = {f(x): x ∈ X} = {y ∈ Y : ∃x ∈ X (y = f(x))}

Isn't this just the whole range of the function? My intuition tells me it should be x ∈ A, but I don't want to assume a typo. If it is the whole range, why introduce the subset A?

Comment: Another notation for $f[A]$ is $ f''A$ (read $f$-double-prime $A$ or $f$-double-tick $A$). In  other subjects, it is often assumed (without stating so) that  $X$ is anti-transitive, that is, that members of $X$ are not subsets of $X$, and $f[A]$ is then written as  $f(A)$ without ambiguity.  But in set theory we often study sets that are not anti-transitive,  for example,  non-$0$ ordinals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a typo, and it should require $x\in A$ instead of $x\in X$.